# PHP Source Control Server

Tags: php, svn, version-control

I there a PHP based source control 'server' that is compatible with SVN clients?
I'd like to host my SVN on my hosting servers, however the current host will not allow me to start any process or install any software

Comment: I could build one but I don't want to spend the time if I don't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a PHP front end but you will still need to have the SVN server running somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

You could try:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/deltaweb

Comment: Looks like its going in the right direction, however it's beta.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of.

You can look at services like [CVSDude.org](http://cvsdude.com/) which provide great SVN hosting that's pretty affordable. They basically specialize in both CVS, and now SVN hosting.

Comment: That is fine, but does not address the problem. On a side note www.xp-dev.com allows free svn hosting up to 1500MB

Comment: I don't think there is a solution. And the question is why would you want to push it unless it's your core competency? I would instead recommend outsourcing, especially since it can be done so cheaply. And it's not a good thing to have your SVN on the same box as your hosting box.

Comment: As for hosting, just remember nothing is free. You'll get what you pay for... And for us, source control is very important. I'd rather entrust someone I know is an expert and that's their core business on our source than someone who is offering it for free. But that's just me ;)

Comment: I do believe that they have paid accounts and I am using them now with no problems.

Comment: I don't know enough about them to make a valid judgement, all I can say is be careful. This is your source after all ;)

Answer (score 0):

The only PHP-based SVN project I'm aware of is this package that allows PHP to utilize some of the SVN bindings: http://pecl.php.net/package/svn.

As the other answers here have indicated, I don't think you are going to find what you want.  A PHP-based SVN server does not appear to exist.

I would suggest finding a different hosting provider for your repositories.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a hosted svn repository and you don't mind using and trusting a 3rd party, try [beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/), they have a free account and a number of fairly reasonable paid options, considering the management overhead you won't need with them.