# Is There a PHP SVN Server

Tags: php, svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Source Control Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368958/php-source-control-server)

Hello,

I know there is a SVN Extension for php before some one comments on that.

I'm asking for a php SVN Server as i would like to read how SVN's save the changes as i want to do the same ting but use mysql Database instead for my content allso i would like to see how it's formed when the latest Repo is downloaded so i could do with project.

I dont mind other scripting langs just no compiled application posting please

EDIT
Ok what im looking for is the method svn uses to detect and save changes.
And the method used to construct the end result file when downloading a repo

THIS is not for me to build on SVN its for me to build a System that replicates the 2 parts mentioned above

Awnser ----------------------------
http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.text.text-diff.intro.renderers.php

Comment: [Possible duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368958/php-source-control-server)

Comment: asked for answer though. question is unanswered to the point of what i need

Comment: This is not a Duplicate i edited before the Closing why has this been closed i explain how it was not a duplicate Question.

Comment: Consider it a lesson in communication. If you work on formulating clear, unambiguous questions they won't be closed as duplicates of different questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your interested in looking into the data format they use, do you know SVN has a Berkeley DB backend?

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.create.html

```
svnadmin create --fs-type bdb /var/svn/repos
```

Comment: is there any way i can see the Database from out side SVN

Comment: I haven't used Berkeley DB for years and years so don't know for certain ... but I would guess so. Just get your own copy and point it at the files SVN makes. Worth a try at least.

Comment: Yes, you can look at the BDB database files directly. However, since SVN is using the key/value pair API, you will have to read the database using their data structures (which you can probably infer from the SVN package). Once you know what the data structures look like, you can write a C, C++, Java or PHP application to read the database. The PHP API for BDB is included with the BDB download here: http://bit.ly/gNWr1C.